# JS - create and pass a function, that is to be evaluated within the context of another scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working with angular and bootstrap tour and I want to try and keep the objects in an area of their own, so they don't have to be stored in the controller. I want to store an object in the service, but it also has functions in the object. When those get "eval()" 'd, they are firing in the scope of the service, instead of the controller where they are passed. Specifically, "$scope" has no context in the service, but does in the controller.

Heres a sample of the code:

```
var returnedObj = {
    steps: [
        {
            element: '#newProduct',
            title: 'Create Products',
            placement: 'bottom',
            content: 'Create new products here'
        }
    ],
    backdrop: true,
    //The function that I want to interact with the $scope through the controller
    onShow: function (tour) {
        $scope.tourDisabled = true;
        $scope.filter.availability = 'all';
        $scope.filter.gallery = 'Show All';
        $scope.updateFilter();
    }
};
```

I've tried JSON.stringify and JSON.parse, but it doesn't work with functions. Is this just hopeless to be done?

Aside from $rootScope, is this possible?

Comment: function (tour) Where is tour used in the function? Just pass a parameter that you use and remove the scope...

Comment: @gyc Well, i'm not technically using it in the function. It was simply used in the documentation and I haven't removed it. The $scope interacts with the dom and is used widely in the rest of the controller... I'm just trying to get the function to fire in the context of the controller instead of the service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass in `$scope`, or whatever context you need, as an argument to your function:

```
onShow: function (tour, $scope) {
        $scope.tourDisabled = true;
        $scope.filter.availability = 'all';
        $scope.filter.gallery = 'Show All';
        $scope.updateFilter();
```

Comment: You're welcome. I should have also said that I like this approach as it keeps the function a little less tightly coupled.